# ERROR: Cannot use parentheses when declaring variable with deduced class template specialization type

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

Good afternoon! Can someone explain why an error occurs when using a function where only one vector is passed?

Well, that is, there you can transfer constants without pain: 3, "asdf" 2.3, etc., but named variables are not. But for some reason a crossbreed is possible. Why is this suddenly possible?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename... Args>
struct func
{
  func(const Args&... args)
  {
    std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
  }
};

template <typename... Args>
func(Args...) -> func<Args...>;

int main() 
{
  const std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3 };
  func(v);      // error is here
  func(v, 3);   // no error
  func("asdf"); // no error
}
```

ERROR: Cannot use parentheses when declaring variable with deduced class template specialization type

example: https://godbolt.org/z/jdnce5Gdv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clang's error message is oddly specific – g++ and vc++ only complain about conflicting declarations of `v`– but note that it says "*declaring* a variable".

Since `func` is a type, and you can have parentheses around the identifier in a variable declaration, and because of the "if it can be interpreted as a declaration, it *is* a declaration" rule,

```
func(v);
```

is equivalent to

```
func v;
```

declaring a variable `v` of the type `func`.

Here is a shorter example of the same situation:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int v = 0;
    std::vector<int>(v);
}
```

Comment: Then why is there no error here func(v, 3);? What is the equivalent of this string?

Comment: Because `func(v,3);` can't be a declaration of anything.

Comment: Now that I would learn all this, let's summarize and correct me if I made a mistake!

And so:
When I make a func(v) call;
Because of the "declaring a variable" rule, it interprets this as a variable declaration.

And when I make a func(v, 3) call;
This is taken as a function call.

Right?